# Why Calling Setenv from code Not Working?

Tags: go, scheduling

I have a simple test project which is expected to print goroutine scheduling messages while it is running.

Setting the env from Goland configuration it works. but it doesn't from code like below, the app doesn't print scheduling infomation. Anybody explains what happens ehre?

```
func TestScheduler1() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(10)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        go work(&wg)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    // Wait to see the global run queue deplete.
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
}

func work(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    time.Sleep(time.Second)

    var counter int
    for i := 0; i < 1e10; i++ {
        counter++
    }

    wg.Done()
}
```

init function is like:

```
 func init()  {
    os.Setenv("GOMAXPROCS", "1")
    os.Setenv("GODEBUG", os.Getenv("GODEBUG") + "schedtrace=1000,scheddetail=1")
}
```

Comment: Setting these variables inside the program is _too_ _late_ . Use runtime.GOMAXPROCS to change GOMAXPROCS from inside your code. No way to switch debugging on/off once your code runs.

Comment: stackoverflow shall give poster a chance of knowing why his posts were downvoted! One who downvotes the post shall give a reason also

Comment: @Volker, on the one hand, it makes sense. On the other hand, why does Go SDK provide this method then? What's the point of having `os.Setenv(...)` if calling it will have no effect?

Comment: @Dm os.Setenv does have effect, just not the one the OP thought it would have. I do not understand your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`go` command documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Environment_variables) mentions that `go` examines some environment variables:

> The go command, and the tools it invokes, examine a few different environment variables.

So, env variables are checked before the program starts, i.e in build time. When you set these variables from code, the program already runs.

It works from the IDE since the variables are applied before the compilation, therefore the code runs with all the changes you need.